# How to debug VS 2010 complaining about an unreferenced assembly that, well, isn't referenced?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, assemblies

I converted a solution from VS2008/.NET 3.5 to VS 2010/.NET 4.

I'm getting this:

error CS0012: The type 'xxx.yyy' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'xxx, Version=1.0.0.301, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The thing is, there's no code in the project that uses type xxx.yyy, and also, none of the other assemblies referenced from this project refer to assembly xxx either.

Any suggestions on how I could debug this?

Update: Mistery solved.

Let's say the error is on a line of class A in assembly AAA.

It was caused by the fact that AAA.A implements interface AAA.IA that uses type BBB.B from a referenced assembly BBB.

In turn, the implementation of BBB.B uses the type xxx.yyy that the compiler was complaining about.

Mark Gravell's answer is of course the fix for the problem.

Comment: Does it point to a specific line of code?

Comment: Yes. There are actually *two* errors pointing to the same line about different types (both defined in the same assembly) and there's nothing related to any of those types in that line of code.

Comment: It would help if you would *show* those lines, and anything interesting about any types mentioned in them - e.g. their base types.

Comment: While I was digging through the code in order to paste here the interesting bits in the hierarchy, I found out that, indeed, the class that contained the errors does implement an interface that uses types defined in a referenced assembly zzzz that in turn references assembly xxx and makes use of type xxx.yyy . That's why I couldn't find a direct reference to the type xxx.yyy in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually that means that there is a member on the public API - often an interface or base-type, that is needed. The fix is simple: add the reference. The compiler won't be making it up; that reference must be used *somewhere*, else ***how would the compiler even know about it***. If you give a more specific example, we can probably show why it is needed.

Comment: Regarding how the compiler could know - there are other projects in the solution that do depend on assembly xxx AND on the troublesome assembly. I'll try to just load the problematic project by itself, and see what happens.

Comment: I loaded just the project, and it still gives the errors, so you are on to something. I just need to figure out where the compiler came up with this from.

Comment: It was a referenced assembly that referenced the unreferenced assembly :). I don't quite understand why this doesn't cascade automatically, though - why does it break at compile time? Maybe you can point me at some further reading.